# Is reset_column_information called implicitly after each migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

If I have two migrations, the first one adds a column, and the second one insert value into that column, would I still need to call `reset_column_information` manually at the end of first migration?

or rephrasing the question: is `reset_column_information` called automatically after each migration?

---

I am on Rails 3.2.3, and I believe it used to call `reset_column_information` after each migration. However recently I found out that some values are missing when I insert it into anewly created column. The two migrations are run during one rake task. I think this is a bug but just want some clarification.

---

Update:

I have created a demo app to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/lulalala/migration-bug. The readme shows the step to prepare and reproduce it. I think it is probably a bug and have file it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this comment from Rails issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6939#issuecomment-6738014), Rails 3.2.6 only get a fresh copy of database scheme each time you run `rake db:migrate`. So runnning one migration at a time may help bypass the issue that some new column is not being updated.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong.. but I don't think the comment in your provided link ever says reset_column_information is called each time you call `rake db:migrate`. All it says is that it will be refreshed on each migration, not necessarily by calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call 'reset_column_information' in the migration yourself. And this is only if you add a column and populate it immediately afterwards in the "same migration". Check out [rails guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) for details.